# Openstack Swift installation: admin-openrc

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift

I would like to setup an Openstack Swift cluster on Centos 7 with TempAuth authentication method.

In the prerequisite section of the [official tutorial](https://docs.openstack.org/swift/latest/install/controller-install-rdo.html) it is requested to source the *admin-openrc* script but I am not able to find in any of the official repositories. Any tip?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can download the admin-openrc file from horizon, under:

> Compute => API Access => Download Openstack RC file

Answer (score 1):

These are what you need:

```
export OS_USERNAME=admin
export OS_PASSWORD=yourPassword
export OS_PROJECT_NAME=admin
export OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME=Default
export OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME=Default
export OS_AUTH_URL=http://KeystoneNodeAddress:5000/v3/
export OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3
```